# Visual Studio - Project doesn't show quick actions

Tags: visual-studio-2015

The new Visual Studio 2015's feature called quick actions or "lightbulb" no longer appear in my project. It works fine for other projects that I open, but doesn't work for my current one. So, for example, if I have an unnecessary using in my class - it no longer marks it gray or suggests to remove it.

How can I turn it back on?

[This is how it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5lC3.png)

I tried searching online on how to disable this feature - so maybe I can use that information to turn it on but the only solution I found was going to the project's properties and turning on Code Analysis which didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like ticking and unticking `Enable Code Analysis on Build` in `Project Properites->Code Analysis` and changing the rule set to `Microsoft Managed Recommended Rules` fixed it, somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem for some assemblies on Visual Studio 2017 version 15.2. 
Restarting visual studio worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

I found a way to enable it: just go to folder were your programs are saved and you will find a file named .vscode; inside this, you will have a settings file. Open this in VS Code and you will see error squiggles disabled: just enable it and your lightbulb option is back.